# DISPATCH_QUEUE or NSThread

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have 2 step need to be done one by another:

1- Download XML data from the web and store to the document folder

2- reload that XML data from the Document folder to the table and display

I always get table blank as  the process of downloading is a bit long.

What method should I use here to make sure all the data downloaded and then reload last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual solution is to display some spinner, download the data on a background queue and then update the UI on the main queue:

```
[self showDownloadProgress];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [self downloadXMLData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self hideDownloadProgress];
        [tableView reloadData];
    });
});
```

Comment: This is what I would suggest, too.